# Symfony 4 - Problem with DQL for ordered array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have a "Validateur" entity like :

```
Validateur :
-id
-Validateur (User relation )
-Ordre (could be 0,1,2 ... )
```

And GroupeValidateurs entity like :

```
GroupeValidateurs:
-id
-validateurs (ManyToMany relation with Validateur entity)
-nom
```

I would like to make a query such as findAll () for myValidators group, but that would return the response with the array of validators sorted by the "Order" attribute, in ascending order, such as:

```
- id : 1
- nom : "name Groupe"
- validateurs : array [
                      array[

                      id: 1
                      validateur: 1
                      ordre: 1
                      ],
                      array[

                      id: 2
                      validateur: 4
                      ordre: 2
                      ]
                      array[

                      id: 3
                      validateur: 6
                      ordre: 3
                      ]
]
```

I tried this :

```
public function getValidateursGroupeParOrdre($groupe)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('g')
        ->join('v.validateur', 'g')
        ->select('g.validateurs, g.nom')
        ->where('g.id = :groupe')
        ->orderBy('v.ordre', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('groupe', $groupe)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

but doesn't work.
This is my entities :

GroupeValidateurs:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GroupeValidateursRepository")
 */
class GroupeValidateurs
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Validateur", inversedBy="groupeValidateurs", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $validateurs;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->validateurs = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Validateur[]
     */
    public function getValidateurs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->validateurs;
    }

    public function addValidateur(Validateur $validateur): self
    {
        if (!$this->validateurs->contains($validateur)) {
            $this->validateurs[] = $validateur;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeValidateur(Validateur $validateur): self
    {
        if ($this->validateurs->contains($validateur)) {
            $this->validateurs->removeElement($validateur);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getListeNomValidateurs()
    {
        $liste = [];

        foreach ($this->validateurs as $validateur) {
            $nom = $validateur->getValidateur()->getFullName();
            $liste[] = $nom;
        }

        return $liste;
    }

    public function triGroupeParOrdre()
    {
        $tab = [];

        foreach ($this->validateurs as $validateur) {
            if (count($tab) == 0) {
                $tab[] = $validateur;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Validateur:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Gedmo\Sortable\Sortable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\SortablePosition;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ValidateurRepository")
 */
class Validateur
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\SortablePosition
     */
    private $ordre;

    // /**
    //  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    //  * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    //  */
    // private $validateur;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\GroupeValidateurs", mappedBy="validateurs")
     */
    private $groupeValidateurs;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $validateur;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->groupeValidateurs = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getOrdre(): ?int
    {
        return $this->ordre;
    }

    public function setOrdre(int $ordre): self
    {
        $this->ordre = $ordre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValidateur(): ?User
    {
        return $this->validateur;
    }

    public function setValidateur(User $validateur): self
    {
        $this->validateur = $validateur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|GroupeValidateurs[]
     */
    public function getGroupeValidateurs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->groupeValidateurs;
    }

    public function addGroupeValidateur(GroupeValidateurs $groupeValidateur): self
    {
        if (!$this->groupeValidateurs->contains($groupeValidateur)) {
            $this->groupeValidateurs[] = $groupeValidateur;
            $groupeValidateur->addValidateur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeGroupeValidateur(GroupeValidateurs $groupeValidateur): self
    {
        if ($this->groupeValidateurs->contains($groupeValidateur)) {
            $this->groupeValidateurs->removeElement($groupeValidateur);
            $groupeValidateur->removeValidateur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve your desired result by just [annotating](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/ordered-associations.html#ordering-to-many-associations) your `Groupe` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GroupeValidateursRepository")
 */
class GroupeValidateurs
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Validateur", inversedBy="groupeValidateurs", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"ordre" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $validateurs;
}
```

Then you just retreive your desired group through your repository:

```
$group = $groupeRepository->find($groupId);
dump($group->getValidateurs());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I was looking for !